# Why isn't my PHP Error Handler Echoing All Errors?

Tags: php

I have code that causes 2 errors, 1 from the php function pg_query_params because I've input an invalid query, and the Exception that I throw when the result of that function is false:

```
if (!$res = pg_query_params($this->sql, $this->args)) {
        // note pg_last_error seems to often not return anything
        $msg = pg_last_error() . " " . $this->sql . PHP_EOL . " Args: " . var_export($this->args, true);
        throw new \Exception("Query Execution Failure: $msg");
    }
```

Then I have error handler code which logs the errors and is supposed to echo them. Both errors are logged, but only the last (the thrown exception) is echoed. I'd like both echoed, as the first contains helpful debugging info. I don't understand why both aren't, as I've done some debugging and echo is called for both errors. Is it something related to output buffering or a concurrency issue?

Here is a shortened version of my error handler code. The throwableHandler method is registered with set_exception_handler() and the phpErrorHandler method with set_error_handler(). I haven't included generateMessageBodyCommon() but it simply adds error info to the message body:

```
private function handleError(string $messageBody, int $errno)
{
    // echo
    if ($this->echoErrors) {
        $messageBody .= 'inside echo'; // this goes into the log file for both errors
        echo nl2br($messageBody, false);
    }

    // log
    @error_log($messageBody, 3, $this->logPath);
}

public function throwableHandler(\Throwable $e)
{
    $message = $this->generateMessageBodyCommon($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
    $message .= PHP_EOL . "Stack Trace:" . PHP_EOL . $e->getTraceAsString();
    $this->handleError($message, $e->getCode(), $exitPage);
}

public function phpErrorHandler(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile = null, string $errline = null)
{
    $message = $this->generateMessageBodyCommon($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) . PHP_EOL . "Stack Trace:". PHP_EOL . $this->getDebugBacktraceString();
    $this->handleError($message, $errno, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with '@' -> `@error_log($messageBody, 3, $this->logPath);`

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

## Error level :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

> error_reporting — Sets which PHP errors are reported

Comment: Thanks. I think if I don't use that, and there is something wrong with the error log, there will be an infinite loop. Do you think this could have something to do w/ the echo problem?

Comment: error_reporting or maybe `ini_set('display_errors', true);` ?

Comment: error_reporting( -1 ); // all, including future types
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'off' );
ini_set( 'display_startup_errors', 'off' ); Note: I just tried setting the ini_set values to on but it had no effect.

Comment: I think the idea is to give control of error output to the custom error handler.

Comment: maybe you have an issue in your handler and this make a loop

Comment: Both errors get logged but not echoed, so I don't think that's it.